# Excel if formula on a range

Tags: excel-formula

How can I apply the if condition on a range of cells?
Let us say I have scores of different subject for a student. I want to return a value "Fail" even if any one of the scores is less than 50. Can this be done with the if conditions on Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"<50")>0,"Fail","Pass")
```

If it finds any value in Column A that is less than 50 it will report Fail.  If not it will report "Pass".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much

Comment: @DianaPaulraj glad to help. Please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do and it will mark the question as being answered.